# How do I implement Extended Euclidean algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, function, scheme

How can I implement the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)? Here's my first attempt:

```
(define ex-gcd a b 
 ; gcd(a,b) = a * x+ b * y 
 ; gcd(a,b)-> always will be 1
 output: (x.y) 
)
```

Comment: Well, that is one poor first attempt...  but at least you got a great answer from +Óscar López!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is right [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Pseudocode) in Wikipedia, you just have to adapt it to only return Bézout coefficients, the `car` part of the returned `cons`-cell will be `x`, and the `cdr` will be `y`:

```
(define (extended-gcd a b)
  (let loop ([s 0] [t 1] [r b]
             [old-s 1] [old-t 0] [old-r a])
    (if (zero? r)
        (cons old-s old-t)
        (let ((q (quotient old-r r)))
          (loop (- old-s (* q s))
                (- old-t (* q t))
                (- old-r (* q r))
                s t r)))))
```

It's easy to test it using [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), use different values for `a` and `b` and verify that it works as advertised:

```
(define (test a b)
  (let* ((ans (extended-gcd a b))
         (x (car ans))
         (y (cdr ans)))
    (= (gcd a b) (+ (* a x) (* b y)))))

(test 384 256)
=> #t
```

Notice that the algorithm calculated other values, by changing what you return you can also obtain the following:

```
Bézout coefficients:     old_s, old_t
Greatest common divisor: old_r
Quotients by the gcd:    t, s
```

Comment: ok, its good but i dont know why in my  
exercise i have one example 
for (17 , 3120) -> second value should be 2753 not 2, cause 17*2753mod3120 = 1

Comment: @user3622243 you're confused, the Bézout coefficients obtained using the extended Euclidean algorithm are not verified using `mod`, you can check that `(= (gcd 17 3120) (+ (* 17 -367) (* 3120 2)))` and besides `17*2753mod3120` is _not_ `1`. Read the links provided in the answer, first you have to understand the subject and get your concepts clear.